# Is there any way to set an icon to the executable that is produced by kotlin native compiler? I use gradle

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

The executable produced after compiling by kotlin native compiler has no icon. Is there any way to set it? I use IntelliJ Idea and Gradle build system

Comment: there is no cross-platform solution for this, because in Linux for example there is no way to embedd the icon into the executable. Which platforms do you work with? Make that clear in you question